# Problems integrating React Redux with Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

so I've been working on integrating Redux with my React app, and when I wrap the Router component with the Provider component and refresh to page, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object is not a function. (In 'Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["useMemo"])', 'Object' is an instance of Object)
```

code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router";

import { createStore } from "redux";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import indexRoutes from "routes/index.jsx";

import "assets/scss/material-kit-pro-react.css?v=1.2.0";

import reducer from "./store/reducer";

var hist = createBrowserHistory();

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
          return (
            <Route path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} />
          );
        })}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

React Version: `16.5.2`

Comment: Please add the code where you ran across this error

Comment: [Here's the Code](https://hastebin.com/kehabiqodu.js)

If I remove the <Provider> element from it, the app works perfectly fine, but when it's there, it's throwing the error.

Comment: Which version of React are you using?

Comment: Currently using version 16.5.2

Comment: React hooks were introduced in v16.8 of React, which your `react-redux` package is using. You can either downgrade react-redux package or upgrade your `react` and `react-dom`

Comment: Thank you so much! Was trying to figure out for a couple hours why it wasn't working.  I updated React & React DOM to the 16.13.0